# Calling C# object from IronPython

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

I have the following C# code to compile it into MyMath.dll assembly.

```
namespace MyMath {
    public class Arith {
        public Arith() {}
        public int Add(int x, int y) {
            return x + y;
        }
    }
}
```

And I have the following IronPython code to use this object.

```
import clr
clr.AddReferenceToFile("MyMath.dll")

import MyMath
arith = Arith()
print arith.Add(10,20)
```

When I run this code with IronPython, I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ipycallcs, line unknown, in Initialize
NameError: name 'Arith' is not defined
```

What might be wrong?

### ADDED

arith = Arith() should have been arith = MyMath.Arith()

Comment: Shouldn't it be arith = MyMath.Arith()?

Comment: @Mark : Yes, that was the problem, thanks.

Comment: for fixing common errors in IronPython try this [Beginning IronPython](http://fireydude.wordpress.com/2013/06/12/beginning-ironpython/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be doing the following:

```
from MyMath import Arith
```

Or:

```
from MyMath import *
```

Otherwise, you'll have to refer to the `Arith` class as MyMath.Arith.