# Argument Confusion Running a C# Method In IronPython

Tags: c#, ironpython

I am trying to run a c# method in the IronPython (2.7.3) console:

The c# (compiled to a dll) is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace PythonTest
{
    public class PythonTest
    {
        public PythonTest(){}
        public int GetOne()
        {
            return 1;
        }
        public double Sum(double d1, double d2)
        {
            return d1+d2;
        }
        public string HiPlanet()
        {
            return "Hi Planeta";
        }
    }
}
```

---

the python is

```
import sys
sys.path.append("Y:\\")
import clr
clr.AddReferenceToFile('./PythonTest')
import PythonTest

a = PythonTest.PythonTest.GetOne()
```

---

I get a TypeError in ironpython saying that the function takes one arguement (which it doesn't according to my c#!). I am confused and woudl appeciate help here, I'm just trying to call some c# functions provide the arguements and get the results, thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a guess, but since `GetOne()` is an instance method, it may be expecting a `this` parameter. You may need to create a new `PythonTest` object first, and then call the method on that instance.

Comment: Is this a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902018/calling-c-sharp-object-from-ironpython?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Since it's an instance method, you need to instantiate the object before calling GetOne method:

```
obj = PythonTest.PythonTest()
a = obj.GetOne()
```

or, in one-liner:

```
a = PythonTest.PythonTest().GetOne()
```